# kendo chart category axis item labels - Set highlighted labels has wrong alignment

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm using kendo chart to render out the charts and I want specific labels to be displayed as a bold text, So for that I'm using **visual** method which help me customize label and render with **createVisual()**

When I add *bold* property to label it is not getting aligned as compared to normal label.

code:

```
const { x, y } = e.rect.origin;
const text = new Text(
                e.text,
                new Point(x, y),
                { font: 'bold 12px "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif' }
            );
const group = new Group();
group.append(text);
return group;
```

If I remove *bold* property then it is working as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add screenshots showing the issue or maybe even recreate it in Stackblitz?

Comment: Have a look here, https://jpllosa.blogspot.com/search/label/kendo%20chart, it has some `createVisual()` examples that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.
Finally I got the solution here it is.

When I was rendering chart Souce Sans Pro font was not getting loaded before kendo render chart so it was using font fall back logic and calculating axis based on that another fonts.

I added font pre loading logic at the index level and now it is working as expected.

This might help others. :)